# How to make items on a rails form sortable

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-4

Using Rails 4 and Ruby 1.9.3.  Styling is handled by an internally developed gem based on bootstrap 3.

I've been looking around for answers to this and have found a number of different examples that show how to do this with a basic list in a view.  The railscast is one such example I've looked at.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/147-sortable-lists

However, I am trying to achieve this in a rails nested form using a partial but having no success.  Sadly I am new to ruby, rails and have no prior knowledge of javascript so this is all a step learning curve.

My service model relates to a places model through service places.  The service_places.position field holds the order of the stops.

My nested form (_form.html.erb) for services is shown below:

```
<!-- Adds the Service_Places (stops) associations via partial (sort applied in model) -->
<div>
  <div class="links" id="sortable">
    <%= link_to_add_association 'Add Stop', f, :service_places, :class => "btn btn-default", :data => {"association-insertion-method" => "after" } %>
  </div>
  <%= f.fields_for :service_places do |service_places| %>
    <%= render 'service_place_fields', :f => service_places %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

My service_place partial is shown below:

```
<!-- This will hold the partial form for service places -->
<div class="nested-fields">
  <%= f.label :service_place, "Stops", :class=>"col-sm-2 control-label" %>
  <div class="col-sm-1">
    <%= f.text_field :position, :class=> "form-control", :placeholder => "Position" %>
  </div>  
  <div  class="col-sm-3">
    <%= f.collection_select :place_id, Place.where('active = true').order(:place_name), :id, :place_name, :prompt => "Select Place" %>
  </div>
  <div>
    <%= link_to_remove_association "Remove Stop", f, :class => "btn btn-default" %>
  </div>
</div>
```

I started looking at trying to assign an ID to each of the service_place partials DIV tags  but couldn't get it to work.

The questions I would like to know are:

1) Is it possible to allow user to reorder items within forms? and save the new order in the server?

2) If it is possible could someone give me a hint on how to go about doing this.

Thanks in advance for taking time to look at this post.

Comment: try `<%= f.fields_for :service_places, f.object.service_places.order('position asc') do |service_places| %>`

Comment: Thanks for the comment Juan.  That not what I am after.  What I am looking for is the user to be able to re-order the data in a form and it update the appropriate position field based on this (probably when submitted).  The answer will involve javascript in some format.  The railscast is a good example of what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: I understand now, please edit your question to make that clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My colleague showed me a way to achieve this using the "acts as list" gem.
His blog can be found here:

http://nicholshayes.co.uk/blog/?p=344

To get this working I made the amendments as shown below.

1) In my service model I added these three methods:

```
  # Used in the positioning of service places using the acts_as_list gem
  def method_missing(symbol, *args, &block)
    if acts_as_list_method?(symbol)
      pass_method_to_service_service_place(symbol, args.first)
    else
      super
    end
  end

  # Used in the positioning of service places using the acts_as_list gem
  def pass_method_to_service_service_place(symbol, service_place)
    raise "A Service_Place is needed for re-ordering places" unless service_place.kind_of? ServicePlace
    service_place.send(symbol) if service_place
  end

  # Used in the positioning of service places using the acts_as_list gem
  def acts_as_list_method?(symbol)
    ActiveRecord::Acts::List::InstanceMethods.instance_methods.include?(symbol.to_sym)
  end
```

2) Added route's

```
  resources :services, :concerns => :paginatable, only: [:create, :destroy, :edit, :index, :new, :show, :update] do

    # Required for the re-ordering of the routes
    resources :service_places do
      member do
        get :move_up
        get :move_down
      end
    end

  end
```

3) Amend the SERVICE show.html

```
<% @service.service_places.reorder("service_places.position asc").each do |serviceplace| %>

  <dd>

    <% if user_signed_in? %>
      <% if @service.first?(serviceplace) %>
        <%= link_to('', move_up_service_service_place_path(serviceplace, service_id: @service), class: "btn btn-default btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up invisible") %>
      <% else %>
        <%= link_to('', move_up_service_service_place_path(serviceplace, service_id: @service), class: "btn btn-default btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up") %>
      <% end %>

      <% if @service.last?(serviceplace) %>
        <%= link_to('', move_down_service_service_place_path(serviceplace, service_id: @service), class: "btn btn-default btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down invisible") %>
      <% else %>
        <%= link_to('', move_down_service_service_place_path(serviceplace, service_id: @service), class: "btn btn-default btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down") %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>

    <!-- Unfortunately this is not very efficient way of showing the place because it calls the db for each item. -->
    <%= Place.find(serviceplace.place_id).place_name %>

  </dd>

<% end %>
```